# what should i do with this error in code of addition of two numbers?

Tags: java, android

A code of addition of two number written in android studio but giving this problem. so, what I have to do with problem ?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCHLY.jpg code of addition application in android studio.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEP41.jpg complete code of addition in android studio

Comment: Please just add your code in the post instead of a picture.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code and error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your method defined outside your class. Use this structure:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         ...
     }

     public void onAddClick(View a){
         ...
     }
}
```